# Prevent PHP showing results in new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**I am trying to get a PHP file to collect directory information, then display this on my current html page.**

I want to prevent the results of the php code opening on a new page(PHP_Function.php), and instead post them on a div on my main html page upon completion of my PHP code.

My html code is as follows:

```
<form id="myFormName" method="post" action="PHP_Function.php">

        <input type="submit" class="learnButton" name="insert" value="Find Available Evidence" />

    </form>

        <script>
    $(function(){
          $("#myFormName").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: $(this).attr('action'),
                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function(data)
                     {                 
                        //display data...
                        //("#results").html(data.name).show; 
                        //console.log(data);
                        $("#results").append(data.name); 
                        }

                   });

          });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="results"></div>
```

And PHP code I have an array I wish to post on my main html page (*IfPresentArray*) for which I have tried:

```
echo json_encode($IfPresentArray);
```

Furthermore, this code does correctly give me the results I want, but I want them to be written to *"results"* div. And **NOT OPEN A NEW PHP PAGE WITH THE RESULTS**

I think to do this I must use **JSON** and **AJAX** to post the results back to the page, but I am struggling to do this and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You're missing closing bracket for `$(function(){`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to prevent the form from making a HTTP request.

```
$("#myFormName").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
```

This works better than `return false;` as any failures in the JavaScript will mean the return statement is never reached and the form will fire the HTTP request. So you can now remove `return false;`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json', // this is what you expect back from the php (i.e. json, html, etc)
    success: function(data) {                 
        // data will be your json array or object
        console.log(data); // will allow you to see return data in web browser inspection tools
        $("#results").append(data.name).show(); // show is a function (only needed if you hide the results div to start with).
    }
 });
```

Then just check the brackets on the rest of your JavaScript matches up. Using a program with syntax highlighting usually helps with that.

Comment: really appreciate your help. I have made the suggested changes to the code. The when calling the PHP_Function.php file, it seems to open the page in the browser, and displays the results there as JSON, instead of returning to the desired div: _" results"_. I was hoping to prevent this.

Comment: Make sure you've added `event` to to function handler on the submit function and then the `event.preventDefault();` line directly underneath.

Comment: Ah...I have amended. Im getting an error in the console: _"Uncaught TypeError; undefined is not a function."_

For this line of code: `("#results").append(data.name); `

Comment: I was missing the **"$"**  typical! but still not showing in my results div.
However it is returning the array in the console.

Comment: You mean the `json` data, not an array :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was the lack of brackets / incorrect syntax.
Specifically in the code:

```
("#results").append(data);
```

Was missing a **$** at the start.

Thanks to @diggersworld (and logical thinking)

The modified and completed code is shown below:

```
<form id="myFormName" method="post" action="PHP_Function.php">

        <input type="submit" class="learnButton" name="insert" value="Find Available Evidence" />

    </form>

    <script>
    $(function(){
          $("#myFormName").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: $(this).attr('action'),
                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function(data)
                     {                 
                        //display data...
                        //("#results").html(data.name).show; 
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#results").append(data); 
                        }

                   });

          });
        });
    </script>
```

and the PHP code remaining the same:

```
echo json_encode($IfPresentArray);
```